# ¿Cómo puedo deshabilitar el pop-up de Google Chrome "¿Quieres volver a cargar este sitio web?"?

Tags: formularios, eventos, chrome, extjs, cámara

Estoy desarrollando un formulario con extJs donde en un campo necesito subir una imagen. El problema ocurre cuando abro la cámara desde un botón del propio formulario, ya que al realizar la foto y volver al mismo, me aparece un pop-up indicando si quiero volver a cargar el sitio Web, entorpeciendo la experiencia de usuario
He probado a añadir event.preventDefault(), pero necesito omitir dicho pop-up y que, a su vez, no recargue el formulario ni me haga perder la información que ya estaba rellena.

Mencionar también que lo he probado en otro dispositivo similar (tablet) y no me aparece dicho pop-up.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí].

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Si la pregunta tiene relación con Selenium, esto podría servirte https://stackoverflow.com/a/55590017/13419694